# Как сделать проверку в axios запросе

Tags: массивы, reactjs, axios

Как сделать проверку в axios запросе post если есть пользователь то регистрируем если нету перевести На страницу регистрации.
В этом запросе только если вводить того пользователя который есть в БД то все получается а если того которого нету вылезет ошибка и даже правильного пользователя не пропускает.
Вот код запроса:

```
export const auth = (name, email, pass) =>{

    return async dispatch => {
        try{
            const response2 = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/login`, {
            name,
            email,
            pass
        })
            dispatch(setUser(response2.data))
            localStorage.setItem('pass', response2.data.pass)  
        }catch(e){
            //alert(e.response2.data)
        }
    } 
}
```

А то если ввожу другого пользователя вылетает ошибка и ломается сервер.

Вот ошибка:

```
xhr.js:220          POST http://localhost:5000/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Код сервера:

```
async getOneUser (req, res) {
        try{ 
                    (async()=>{
                        const { name, email, pass} = req.body
               db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$1::text AND email=$2::text', [name, email] , (err, row) =>{
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error executing query', err.stack);
                    }
                    (async()=>{
                        const hash = await bcrypt.compare(pass, row.rows[0].pass)
                        if(hash){
                            res.json(row.rows)
                        }else{
                            res.json({"message": "Такого пользователя нет"})
                        }
                    })();
                    
                });
            })();
            }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            res.send({message: "Ошобка сервера getOneUser"})

        }  
    }
```

Ошибка в консоле:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\controller\user.controller.js:76
                        const hash = await bcrypt.compare(pass, row.rows[0].pass)   
                                                                            ^       

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pass')
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\controller\user.controller.js:76:77   
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\controller\user.controller.js:82:23   
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:421:18)
    at Query.handleReadyForQuery (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:139:14)
    at Client._handleReadyForQuery (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:290:19)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fullstack\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: У вас походу сервер падает, когда делает запрос по пользователю, которого нет в ваше БД

Comment: Как-то возможно это исправить?

Comment: Возможно, но для этого надо видеть код сервера, где он делает запрос в БД, как его парсит ну и ошибку сервера тоже не плохо было бы увидеть

Comment: Вам пришел мой код сервера?

Comment: Причины ошибки и способы устранения [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pass')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сервере(пример)

```
async getOneUser(req, res) {
  try {
    const {name, email, pass} = req.body;
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$1::text AND email=$2::text', [name, email], async (err, row) => {
      if (!err) {
        if (row.rows && row.rows.length) {
          const hash = await bcrypt.compare(pass, row.rows[0].pass);
          if (hash) {
            res.json(row.rows)
          } else {
            res.json({"message": "Пароли не совпали"})
          }
        } else {
          res.json({"message": "Такого пользователя нет"})
        }
      } else {
        console.error(`Error executing query ${err}`, err.stack);
        res.json({error: err.message, stack: err.stack})
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Ошибка выборки пользователя из БД ${e}`, e);
    res.send({message: `Ошибка сервера getOneUser: ${e}`, stack: e.stack});
  }
}
```

Основная ошибка была в том, что вы не проверяли данные, которые к вам возвращаются из БД. Вам сервер присылал массив `row.rows` нулевой длины, а вы обращались к первому элементу, которого не было, вот и получали ошибку. `try catch` не срабатывал, т.к. вы использовали анонимные функции с замыканием, для таких функций `try catch` должен быть установлен внутри функций.

На клиентской части - В случае успеха, вы возвращаете массив `row.rows`, если не успех, то возвращаете объект. Вам необходимо либо стандартизировать ответ от сервера, либо предусмотреть это на клиентской части.

Получая ответ на клиенте, вы не задумываясь передаете `response2.data` а `data` может отсутствовать. Надо поставить как минимум проверку `if (response2 && response.data)`. Сейчас, когда сервер ответит, допустим, нет пользователя, на этой строчке все сломается.

Пример на клиентской части

```
export const auth = (name, email, pass) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const response2 = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/login`, {
        name,
        email,
        pass
      })
      if (response2 && response2.data) {
        dispatch(setUser(response2.data))
        if (response2.data.pass) {
          localStorage.setItem('pass', response2.data.pass)
        } else {
          console.log('Нет свойства pass в объекте response2.data.pass')
        }
      } else {
        console.error(`Ошибка от сервера`, response2);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Ошибка обработки ответа от сервера`, e);
    }
  }
}
```

Это все только примеры реализации проверок и защиты от обращения к undefined. 
 Не понимаете, где происходит ошибка, обкладывайтесь console.log и выводите всю цепочку объекта. На примере вашего `row` сервера: `console.log(row); console.log(row.rows); console.log(row.rows[0]); console.log(row.rows[0].pass);`