# Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading ***)

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, методы

Периодически, при разработке на `JavaScript` возникает ошибка: **Cannot read property *** of undefined** или **Cannot read property *** of null**

Например в этом коде:

```
const count = result.data.length;
```

> **Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'length')**

Или в этом:

```
const dataMap = response.lines.map(item => item * 2);
```

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

Как понять причину ошибки, что оно означает, почему появляются и как ее исправить?

Comment: [Uncaught TypeError: *** is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cannot read property of undefined/null (reading 'method')

> Ошибка нам говорит, что мы пытаемся вызвать свойство или метод `method` объекта, в то время, как сам объект являет **null** или **undefined**

Рассматривать будем на примере данного объекта

```
const data = {
    name: 'TypeError',
    message: '',
    errors: null,
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}
```

Ошибка возникнет, если мы попытаемся выполнить следующий код:

```
data.errors.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // null.forEach()
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')**

```
data.values.map(item => console.log(item)); // undefined.map()
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

Данные ошибки говорят нам о том, что мы пытаемся вызвать методы у ничего(*null* или *undefined*).
`data.errors` это **null**. У null нет методов. А `data.values` вообще не существует. Нельзя вызвать метод у того, что не существует.

Так же, если объявить переменную и попытаться вызвать у нее какой либо метод без инициализации, то получим ошибку(в данном случае **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')**):

```
const arr;
arr.push(1); // undefined.push();
```

##### Cannot read property

> **of undefined** - ключ не определен, т.е. отсутствует в объекте.
> **of null** - ключ в объекте есть, но имеет значение **null**. У `null` нет методов.

### Как понять, где возникла ошибка?

В **Node.JS**:

```
file:///C:/dev/nodeserver/SO/11.js:10 // Номер строки
data.errors.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // null.forEach()
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
    at ←[90mfile:///C:/dev/nodeserver/SO/←[39m11.js:10:13
←[90m    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)←[39m
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
←[90m    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)←[39m
←[90m    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)←[39m
←[90m    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)←[39m
```

Здесь **at ←[90mfile:///C:/dev/nodeserver/SO/←[39m11.js:10:13** мы видим номер строки с ошибкой и позицию, где произошла ошибка.

В **браузере** это выглядит так:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
    at 123.html?_ijt=vkfkm1ubo3ut5c02m72ihg4lgu:72:15
```

где 72 это номер строки, а 15 это точка, где возникла ошибка.

### Как этого избежать?

Проверять, что приходит в объекте и существуют ли в объекте нужные нам значения. Один из вариантов проверки, воспользоваться `console.log()`.
Можно начать с последнего ключа, однако лучше весь пусть вывести, что бы понимать структуру, с которой работаем:

```
console.log(data) // { name: 'TypeError', message: '', errors: null, sayHi: [Function] }
console.log(data.errors) // null
```

Так же можно воспользоваться оператором необязательной цепочки вызовов '**?.**'

```
const a = data?.errors?.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // null.forEach()
const b = data?.values?.map(item => console.log(item)); // undefined.map()
```

Оператор **необязательной цепочки вызовов** будет проверять значение слева. Если значение `null` или `undefined`, цепочка прерывается и возвращается значение **undefined**.

Для объявленных переменных указывать тип данных

```
const arr = []; // Указываем, что меременная это массив
arr.push(1); // Можем воспользоваться любым методом массива;
```