# Как исправить ошибку в Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Создаю свой первый проект на Нексте и сразу же столкнулся с ошибкой развертывания.(никаких других библиотек не загружал)
Получаю ошибку на локальном хосте:

> Failed to compile
> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[11].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[11].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Проект был создан стандартными командами:

> npm create next-app --typescript

Comment: Можете показать код, на котором происходит ошибка?

Comment: Я код вообще не писал, идет стандартная разметка Некста

Comment: Ищите по коду, где упоминается **config**. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Answer (score 0):

в корне проекта удали папку .next
и выполни команду:

- npm run build
- npm run dev

Comment: Попробовал несколько раз, не помогает, выдает такую же ошибку : " ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[11].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[11].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')"

Comment: Приложение работает только когда я удаляю все стили и их импорты отовсюду. Как только я верну globals.css либо создам свой css все крашится. Какой-то трабл со стайлс