# Как при кастомной валидации вернуть значение true?

Tags: javascript

Есть кастомная валидация input-ов, написанная на js:

```
const validateForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const nameValue = document.querySelector("#cardName").value;
  const numberValue = document.querySelector("#number").value;
  const monthValue = document.querySelector("#month").value;
  const yearValue = document.querySelector("#year").value;
  const cvcValue = document.querySelector("#cvc").value;

  const errorName = document.querySelector("#errorName");
  const errorNumber = document.querySelector("#errorNumber");
  const errorDate = document.querySelector("#errorDate");
  const errorCvc = document.querySelector("#errorCvc");

  if (nameValue.length < 5 || nameValue.length > 25) {
    errorName.innerText = "Wrong format, please fill in the field";
return false;
  } else {
    errorName.innerText = "";
  }

  if (numberValue.length < 19) {
    errorNumber.innerText = "Wrong format, please fiil in the field";
return false;
  } else {
    errorNumber.innerText = "";
  }

  if (monthValue.length < 2 || yearValue.length < 2) {
    errorDate.innerText = "Can't be blank";
return false;

  } else {
    errorDate.innerText = "";
  }

  if (cvcValue.length < 3) {
    errorCvc.innerText = "Can't be blank";
return false;
  } else {
    errorCvc.innerText = "";
  }
return true;
};
```

Она проверяет поля на определённые значения, если они не соответствуют, я через DOM вывожу в span определённый текст и возвращаю false. Если всё хорошо, валидация возвращает true.

И у меня есть кнопка submit

```
<input type="submit" onclick="changeForm()">
```

И есть функция, которая проверяет, если validateForm === true, то оно выводит алёрт с сообщением верно, если нет, то соответсвенно не верно.

```
function changeForm() {
  if(validateForm === true) {
alert("верно");
} else {
alert("Неверно");
}
```

Но оно возвращает всегда "Неверно". Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы сравниваете функцию со значением.

Что бы вызвать функцию, надо написать `validateForm()`

```
function changeForm() {
  if(validateForm() === true) {
    alert("верно");
  } else {
    alert("Неверно");
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, я понял свою ошибку, спасибо! Ещё хотел спросить одну вещь, у меня теперь в консоли выдаёт ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault'), когда нажимаю на кнопку. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Вот описание ошибки [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Вы не передаете в фукнцию значение **e**

Answer (score 1):

> Но оно возвращает всегда "Неверно". Почему?

Поскольку нет собственно запуска функции `validateForm`, твое условие `validateForm === true` - ложно.

Перепиши функцию `changeForm` следующим образом

```
function changeForm() {
  const mess = validateForm() ? "Верно" : "Неверно"
  alert(mess);
}
```