# почему не могу получить элемент из массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

хочу сделать запрос на сервер и получить объект, с этого объекта хочу получить поле weather, это массив объектов, но мне нужен только первый, и с него хочу получить поле main. Если не обновлять страницу то все работает. Если обновить то вылезает ошибка

> CurrentWeather.jsx:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так.

*получаю нужный объект*

```
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({})
const [getWeather, isWeatherLoading, weatherError] = useFetching(async () => {
    const resopose = await axios.get(url)
    setCurrentWeather(resopose.data)
})
useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentCity()
        getWeather()
    }, [city, urlForCurrentCity])
```

*далее пытаюсь его вывести*

```
isWeatherLoading
               ? 
               <Loader/>
               :
               <div>{currentWeather?.weather[0]?.main}</div>
```

*хук useFetching*

```
import {useState} from "react";

export const useFetching = (callback) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const fetching = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            await callback()
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e.message)
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }
    return [fetching, isLoading, error]
}
```

*объект, который прилетает с сервера*

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.1257,
        "lat": 51.5085
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 0.18,
        "feels_like": 0.18,
        "temp_min": -2.43,
        "temp_max": 1.98,
        "pressure": 1035,
        "humidity": 88
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 0,
        "deg": 0
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 5
    },
    "dt": 1674330102,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 2006068,
        "country": "GB",
        "sunrise": 1674287636,
        "sunset": 1674318546
    },
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос [Cannot read property of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Ваш weather это undefined потому как currentWeather это объект и проверку `isWeatherLoading?` пройдет.

Comment: SwaD, извините, но мне кажется что нет. Я не понимаю почему некоторые поля, например currentWeather?.main?.temp или currentWeather?.main?.humidity я могу получить, а то что написано в вопросе нет, я не понимаю почему оно undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент первоначального рендеринга, ваш **currentWeather** является пустым объектом. У пустого объекта нет ключа **weather**, что и приводит к ошибке [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o).

Как исправить?

Вариант один:

> Сделать начальное состояние, содержащее ключ **weather**

```
const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({ weather: []})
```

Вариант два:

> В рендеринге проверить, что массив существует

```
isWeatherLoading
    ? 
    <Loader/>
    :
    {currentWeather?.weather?.lenght > 0 && 
        <div>{currentWeather.weather[0].main}</div>
    }
```

Comment: спасибо больше, первый способ помог, второй ошибку не вызывает, но информацию тоже не выводит