# Дублирование Froala

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Дублируется Froala editor, при этом вставляется он всего один раз. Так же при этом в консоль выходит ошибка, скорее всего это как-то связано.[image: Ошибка][image: Дублирование]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading \*\*\*)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD, не возможно, так как это node-module, и сам я его исправить вряд ли смогу