# Почему в классе возникает ошибка Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')?

Tags: javascript

Добавь классу Admin следующие свойства и методы.

Публичное свойство blacklistedEmails для хранения чёрного списка почтовых адресов пользователей. Значение по умолчанию это пустой массив.

Публичный метод blacklist(email) для добавления почты в чёрный список. Метод должен добавлять значение параметра email в массив хранящийся в свойстве blacklistedEmails.

Публичный метод isBlacklisted(email) для проверки почты в чёрном списке. Метод должен проверять наличие значения параметра email в массиве хранящемся в свойстве blacklistedEmails и возвращать true или false.

После объявления класса мы добавили инициализацию экземпляра и вызовы методов в той последовательности, в которой твой код будут проверять тесты. Пожалуйста ничего там не меняй.

```js
class User {
  email;

  constructor(email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  get email() {
    return this.email;
  }

  set email(newEmail) {
    this.email = newEmail;
  }
}
class Admin extends User {
  static AccessLevel = {
    BASIC: "basic",
    SUPERUSER: "superuser",
  };
  // Change code below this line
  blacklistedEmails;

  constructor({email, accessLevel}) {
    super(email);
    this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
  }

  blacklist({email}) {
    this.blacklistedEmails.push(email);
  }

  isBlacklisted({email}) {
    return blacklistedEmails.includes(email);
}}

const mango = new Admin({
  email: "mango@mail.com",
  accessLevel: Admin.AccessLevel.SUPERUSER,
});

console.log(mango.email); // "mango@mail.com"
console.log(mango.accessLevel); // "superuser"

mango.blacklist("poly@mail.com");
console.log(mango.blacklistedEmails); // ["poly@mail.com"]
console.log(mango.isBlacklisted("mango@mail.com")); // false
console.log(mango.isBlacklisted("poly@mail.com")); // true
```

Ошибка: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')**, не могу понять, что не так.

Comment: Что за ошибка? Где ошибка?

Comment: Код не компилируется.

Comment: У вас ошибка [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - посмотрите, тут она представлена. Надеюсь сможете понять, в чем вы ошиблись?

Comment: И еще `({email})` не будет работать при передаче обычных строк. Это называется деструктуризация и работает она для объектов. Замените на (email)

Comment: Решила проблему, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Возникнут новые, заходи )

Answer (score 0):

Рискну с ответом:

```js
class User {
    email;

    constructor(email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    get email() {
        return this.email;
    }

    set email(newEmail) {
        this.email = newEmail;
    }
}
class Admin extends User {

    static AccessLevel = {
        BASIC: "basic",
        SUPERUSER: "superuser",
    };

    constructor({ email, accessLevel }) {
        super(email);
        this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
    }

    blacklistedEmails = [];
    
    blacklist(email) {
        this.blacklistedEmails.push(email);
    }

    isBlacklisted(email) {
        return this.blacklistedEmails.includes(email);
    }
}

const mango = new Admin({
    email: "mango@mail.com",
    accessLevel: Admin.AccessLevel.SUPERUSER,
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]