# Вернуть длину самого короткого слова в строке

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание - вывести длину самого короткого слова в строке. Вот мой код:

```
function findShort(s){
  arr = s.split(' ').map((item)=>item.length).sort().at(0)   
  return arr
}
```

Но в кодварс выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at findShort (test.js:3:11)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:15:24)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)
```

Что не так в коде?

Comment: Вы не объявили переменную arr. Добавьте перед ней var или let

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Comment: А так: let arr = s.split(' ').map((item)=>item.length).sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - вы в функцию не передали **s**

Comment: Значит либо забыли передать параметр `s` в функцию, либо передаёте переменную, которая не была инициализирована, и, соответственно, хранит значение `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

> вывести длину самого короткого слова в строке

Предложу такой вариант.

```js
function findShort(s){
  return s.split(' ').reduce((m, v) => v.length < m ? v.length : m, Infinity)
}

const s = '123 456 8888888 12 90'
console.log(findShort(s))
```

Или еще вот такой

```js
function findShort(s){
  return Math.min(...s.split(' ').map(item => item.length))
}

const s = '123 456 8888888 12 90'
console.log(findShort(s))
```

Если действовать по мотивам ТСа - нужно изменить концовку

```js
function findShort(s){
  return s.split(' ').map((item)=>item.length).sort()[0]   
}

const s = '12 345 6'
console.log(findShort(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм, интересная задачка, решил сделать таким образом:

Через регулярку берём слова больше 2х букв, потом сортируем их по длине и выводим первый вариант.
Т.к. автору нужна именно длина, то в конце `[0].length`..

```js
const findShort = str => str.match(/([a-zа-я]{2,})/gim).sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length)[0].length;

console.log(findShort('Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.'));
```