# Не работает второй экземпляр Froala Editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript

При динамическом создании второго экземпляра редактора Froala Editor (при нажатии на кнопку), выходит ошибка. Используется react + ts[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дублика вопроса [Почему возникает ошибка uncaught typeerror cannot read property of undefined (reading 'on')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Answer (score 0):

Всё из-за использования React.StrictMode. Странно, что я сразу не догадался, так как появлялся второй экземпляр компонента.

Comment: И как это повлияло?

Comment: @SwaD, по всей видимости, он "рендерил" этот компоненте дважды, сама ошибка пропала, а компонент теперь работает корректно