# Почему не работает счётчик кликов?

Tags: javascript

При нажатие на смайлик внизу должно выводиться количество кликов по нему но этого не происходит выдает ошибку `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (let btn of buttons) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let counter = btn.closest('.count-click');
        counter.innerText = parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
}
.button {
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: snow;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="list-buttons" id="listButtons">
            <li><button class="button" id="btn1">&#128512</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn2">&#128515</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn3">&#128516</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn4">&#128513</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn5">&#128518</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Так у вас ошибка [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest  closest() возвращает ближайший РОДИТЕЛЬСКИЙ элемент с указанным селектором

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (let btn of buttons) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let counter = btn.nextElementSibling; // обращаемся к следующему элементу-соседу
        counter.innerText = parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
}
.button {
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: snow;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="list-buttons" id="listButtons">
            <li><button class="button" id="btn1">&#128512</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn2">&#128515</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn3">&#128516</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn4">&#128513</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
            <li><button class="button" id="btn5">&#128518</button>
                <p class="count-click">0</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, можете добавить немного текста с объяснениями для вашего ответа)