# Экспонировать operator []

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

Как при экспонировании объекта из c++ в js предоставить доступ к члену `operator []` ?
Т.е. хочется, чтобы объект выглядел в js как массив.

Для встраивания JS использую движок [QJSEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html).

Пытаюсь:

```
struct TablePrototype
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(int rows    READ getRowCount) // ok
    Q_PROPERTY(int columns READ getColumnCount)

    int getRowCount() const;
    int getColumnCount() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant operator [] ( int index ) const; // не работает.
}
```

Ошибок компиляции не получаю, но в run-time: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Т.е. Нужет метод с каким-то специальным именем?

Comment: Ошибка JS говорит о том, что [пришло undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)(ничего). Ну или вы у ничего пытались обратится к свойству '0'

Comment: @SwaD , так я и хотел обратиться к свойству 0. Точнее я хотел чтобы был вызван метод `operator[](0)` на стороне c++. Т.е. я хотел что-то вроде виртуального массива: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396523/can-i-make-a-virtual-array-in-javascript , но не понимаю как использовать `Proxy`, при экспонировании объектов через QJSEngine / qmlRegisterExtendedType.

Comment: Я не сишник, а джаваскриптер, поэтому подсказать, только почему на стороне браузера(ну или где выполняется), такое вылезает...

Answer (score 1):

Кажется [QQmlListProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmllistproperty.html) то что вам нужно. Тут [Extending QML - Object and List Property Types Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-referenceexamples-properties-example.html) пример регистрации такой проперти-списка с соответствующими функциями добавления, обращения по индексу, удаления и прочих.

Comment: К сожалению, этот способ предполагает: (1) модификацию родительского объекта (который будет владеть таблицей в качестве своего члена), а не собственно объекта-таблицы (это в моем случае сильно увеличивает работу, но решается). (2) Не удается унаследоваться от QQmlListProperty и ввести общественные свойства массива, кроме []. а это приведет к необходимости переписывать код на стороне JS.

Comment: Боюсь это единственный способ.  QQmlListProperty реализует встроенный тип проперти list<QObject> на стороне js.