# Почему не выводятся данные из fetch запроса в элементы на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, асинхронность

```js
class MyWeather extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ODESA&units=metric&APPID=5d066958a60d315387d9492393935c19')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }


    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        const srcURL = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0]['icon']}.png`;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>City: {data.name}</h1>
                <p>Temperature: {Math.round(data.main.temp)}&deg;C</p>
                <p>Pressure: {data.main.pressure} hPa</p>
                <p>Description: {data.weather[0]['description']}</p>
                <p>Humidity: {data.main.humidity}%</p>
                <p>Speed: {data.wind.speed}m/s</p>
                <p>Degree: {data.wind.deg}&deg;</p>
                <img src={srcURL} alt='Weather' title='Weather'/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyWeather />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

В консоли есть ошибка:

> **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может есть ошибки? Стейт меняется? Что приходит в запросе?

Comment: куча проблема: начиная с неверного заполнения `srcURL` и заканчивая неверным значением в `data`.

Comment: По указанному запросу отдается один объект. Если ты хотел получить массив - тебе надо использовать какой-то другой адрес для запроса

Comment: @SwaD ошибок вообще никаких нет. Данный код я писал опираясь на документацию `React`, в документации все работало, а у меня почему-то не хочет :(

Comment: @NANO_996, ошибки есть. Если у тебя ничего не было - скорее всего ты просто нигде не использовал сам компонент.

Comment: @Grundy мне нужно именно с этим адресом реализовать запрос и вывод данных

Comment: @NANO_996, это невозможно, так как там нет данных, которые ты ожидаешь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy компонент использовал неоднократно проверял

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144499/discussion-between-grundy-and-nano-996).

Comment: @SwaD сейчас появились в консоли ошибки, прикрепляю к вопросу фото

Comment: Посмотрите, что означает ошибка [Cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана тем, что при первом рендериге не проверяются значения на их существование.

Необходимо в render добавить проверку, что в `this.state.data` есть данные.

Допустим, в качестве примера, проверить, что в **data** есть ключ **name**:

```
render() {

  const { data } = this.state;
  if (data.name) {
    const srcURL = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0]['icon']}.png`;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>City: {data.name}</h1>
        <p>Temperature: {Math.round(data.main.temp)}&deg;C</p>
        <p>Pressure: {data.main.pressure} hPa</p>
        <p>Description: {data.weather[0]['description']}</p>
        <p>Humidity: {data.main.humidity}%</p>
        <p>Speed: {data.wind.speed}m/s</p>
        <p>Degree: {data.wind.deg}&deg;</p>
        <img src={srcURL} alt='Weather' title='Weather'/>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null; // Или что то другое, говорящее, что компонент ожидает данные
  }
}
```

В больших проектах, я бы рекоменовал избавляться в методе render от создания ненужных переменных и обращаться к `this.state.data`

Более красивый вариант:

```
render() {
  const {data} = this.state;
  if (!data.name) return null;
  const srcURL = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0]['icon']}.png`;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>City: {data.name}</h1>
      <p>Temperature: {Math.round(data.main.temp)}&deg;C</p>
      <p>Pressure: {data.main.pressure} hPa</p>
      <p>Description: {data.weather[0]['description']}</p>
      <p>Humidity: {data.main.humidity}%</p>
      <p>Speed: {data.wind.speed}m/s</p>
      <p>Degree: {data.wind.deg}&deg;</p>
      <img src={srcURL} alt='Weather' title='Weather'/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: лучше инвертировать условие и убрать `else`, хотя он и тут не нужен.

Comment: @Grundy Зачем условие инвертировать? А про else, на сколько я помню, реакт должен возвращать null, если компонент ничего не рендерит. Если только что для красоты... Для понимания, этот вариант больше подходит, как мне кажется

Comment: @Grundy Финальный вариант реализации, думаю иницатор сам для себя реализует по потребностям... Может захочет чего другое отображать, например "Ждем данные о погоде"...

Comment: `else` повышает вложенность. Инвертировав условие будет простой `return null` и дальше код будет на прежней вложенности

Comment: @Grundy Да, согласен. Так будет красивее. Добавлю это в ответ.

Comment: @SwaD я сделал как вы написали но ошибки все равно остались. Могли бы вы подсказать что я делаю не так.  Добавил фото в вопрос.

Comment: @NANO_996 Вы не делаете так, как написано. Нет проверки `if` на `data.name`. У вас ошибка будет на 62, когда попробуете счиать из ничего элемент массива. Поставьте, как во втором примере `if (!data.name) return null;` перед 62 строкой и заработает

Comment: @SwaD я сделал как вы посоветовали, но ошибки остались и ничего не выводится. Добавил фото к вопросу

Comment: @NANO_996 Потому что вы не исправив одну ошибку, создали вторую. В `fetch` в цепочке `then` вы проверяете **response.ok**, однако далее ничего не возвращаете(нет **return**) и в следующий вызов `then` поступает `undefined`, вот он вам и затирает исходный объект `{}` в `undefined`. Верните первоначальный вид в fetch и все заработает. После этого уже меняйте fetch под необходимые проверки.