# Formik React выбрасывает ошибку при работе с массивами внутри объектов: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, formik

У меня возникла проблема с работой с массивами, которые находятся на втором - третьем уровне объекта формы `Formik`.

Я вывожу этот массив при помощи `FieldArray`, обращаясь к содержимому  при помощи `arrayHelpers.form.values[arrayHelpers.name].conditions`.

Вывести данные таким образом получается, но возникает другая проблема: при попытке добавить новую строку возникает ошибка:

> **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')**

Полный код с ошибкой на Сэндбоксе
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-williams-6jocp1?file=/src/Formik.tsx:1039-1040

На данный момент элемент `FieldArray` выглядит так:

```
export const FieldArrayConditions = (arrayHelpers: any) => {
    const conditions = arrayHelpers.form.values[arrayHelpers.name].conditions
    return(
    <>
    {conditions.map((_: void, index: number) => {
        return (
            <div key={index} className='form__row-condition'>
                <input type='hidden' name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].id`}/>
                <input type='hidden' name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].margin_id`}/>
                <Field 
                    type='number'
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_from`}
                    component={InputNotLabeled}
                    />
                <Field
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_measure.id`}
                    component={SelectorCurrencies}
                    />
                <span>до</span>
                <Field 
                    type='number'
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_before`}
                    component={InputNotLabeled}
                    />
                <Field
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_measure.id`}
                    component={SelectorCurrencies}
                    />
                <span>=</span>
                <Field 
                    type='number'
                    placeholder='Сумма'
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].margin`}
                    component={InputNotLabeled}
                    />
                <Field
                    name={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_measure_id`}
                    component={SelectorCurrencies}
                    value={`${arrayHelpers.name}.conditions[${index}].price_measure.id`}
                    />
            </div>
        )
    })}
    <div className="form__fieldset">
        <BtnExport text={'Добавить условие'} 
        changeAction={() => arrayHelpers.push(initialConditions)}/>
    </div>
    </>
)}
```

Comment: Как найти и исправить ошибку [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: **arrayHelpers** у вас объект, у которого нет ключа **margin_avia_id**

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен - обращение к массиву через `<FieldArray name="margin_avia_id.conditions"  component={FieldArrayConditions}/>`

Рабочий код https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-williams-6jocp1?file=/src/FieldArrayConditions.tsx