# Как отдебажить ошибку Uncaught Typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode')?

Tags: reactjs

Да, знаю, вопрос типовой, ошибку обсасывали 1000 раз, но в этом конкретном случае я даже причину понять не могу:/ Это странная штука
Сразу скину код который работает ( на классовых компонентах ): https://github.com/yankovalenko94/React_admin_panel/blob/master/Step_4/app/src/components/editor/editor.js
Ниже будет мой код, который я переписываю уже на функциональных компонентах а не на классовых, как по ссылке:
Проблема в функции save, где не хочет работать cloneNode. То есть даже просто банально не хочет автозаполняться, его в списке методов для virtualDom нет при автозаполнении.
https://github.com/nimainikita/saaasken/blob/main/code.js
Перейдите на строку 49, там заветный вызов cloneNode, вызов в консоль переменной в той же функции кончается ошибкой:(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемная часть кода:

```
  const save = () => {
    const newDom = virtualDom.cloneNode(virtualDom); //Копируем данные, лежащие в виртуальном dom
    unwrapTextNodes(newDom); 
    const html = domToString(newDom)
    console.log(html)
  };
```

Comment: Добавьте проблемные части кода в сам вопрос. Как отдебажить ошибку [Uncaught Typescript: Cannot rad properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD Ну сказано - сделано

Comment: Что такое у вас **virtualDom**? Судя по ошибке, он как раз **undefined**

Comment: virtualDom - этакая копия структуры dom, мы ее туда сохраняем.. Сложно объяснить как-то.. 
Делаю админ панель, virtualDom "чистая" копия обычного dom
Блин ну и объяснил
В коде много комментариев которые лучше меня скажут

Comment: Воспользуйтесь советом из ссылки выше и добавьте в самое начало функции `console.log(virtualDom)` и посмотрите, это в данном участке кода

Comment: О да, он undefined..)
Вот как оно получается, я выводил в другой функции этот виртуалДом, там было нормально, но в этой уже не определен)
Как же это поправить, от чего он неопределен в этой функции

Comment: Ищите, где вы его определили, как записываете данные. Посмотрел код ваш, у вас там цепочке .then() от axios запроса. Может ответ не приходит или там и приходит пусто или ошибку где получаете но не перехватываете... Тут только дебаг

Comment: Да, спасибо, я решил эту штуку следующим методом...
Заменил var virtualDom в начале кода на состояние   
const [virtualDom, setVirtualDom] = useState(undefined);

Comment: Ну тогда и `var iframe` переделайте

Comment: Это прекрасно когда ошибка пропала, но появилась та же самая, новая, которая тоже по причине virtualDom undefined))
`  //Запустится когда текст отредактируется
  const onTextEdit = (element) => {
    const id = element.getAttribute("nodeid");
    console.log(virtualDom)
    virtualDom.body.querySelector(`[nodeid="${id}"]`).innerHTML = element.innerHTML; //То что ввел юзер (после равно) записывается в чистую копию
  }
   `
О да, теперь уже BODY не читается))