# Uncaught TypeError: state.post is undefined ошибка в консоли

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В `React Redux Toolkit` добавил

```
reducers: {
    addPost(state, action) {
      const { userimage, title, usertext } = action.payload;    
       state.post.push({
        id: 10,
        userimage,
        title,
        usertext                
       });              
    },
export const { addPost } = postSlice.actions;
```

На странице вызываю

```
dispatch(addPost({ userimage, title, usertext }));
```

При отправке формы получаю ошибку: `state.post is undefined`

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Что за ошибка это понимаете?

Comment: Почитайте про ошибку [state.post is undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o), скорее всего это ваш случай