# Возникает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript

Никак не могу понять, почему оно не работает.

```js
const questions = [
    {
        question: "Question1?",
        answers: [
            {
                text: "a",
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: "b",
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: "c",
                correct: true
            },
            {
                text: "d",
                correct: false
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "Question2?",
        answers: [
            {
                text: "q",
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: "w",
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: "e",
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: "r",
                correct: true
            },
        ]
    }
];

const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
const answerButtons = document.getElementById("answer-buttons");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-btn");

let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
let score = 0;

function startQuiz() {
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    score = 0;
    nextButton.innerHTML = "Next";
    showQuestion();
}

function showQuestion() {
    let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
    let questionNo = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
    questionElement.innerHTML = questionNo + ". " + currentQuestion.question;

    currentQuestion.answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = answer.text;
        button.classList.add("btn");
        answerButtons.appendChild(button);
});
}

startQuiz();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
}

body{
    background: #001e4d;
}

.app{
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
}

.app h1{
    font-weight: 25px;
    color: #001e4d;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.quiz{
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.quiz h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #001e4d;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.btn{
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.btn:hover:not([disabled]){
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn:disabled{
    cursor: no-drop;
}

#next-btn{
    background: #001e4d;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 150px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.correct{
    background: #9aeabc;
}

.incorrect{
    background: #ff9393;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
   <div class="app">
       <h1>Задачи</h1>
       <div class="quiz">
           <h2 id="question">Вопрос</h2>
           <div class="answer-buttons">
               <button class="btn">Ответ1</button>
               <button class="btn">Ответ2</button>
               <button class="btn">Ответ3</button>
               <button class="btn">Ответ4</button>
           </div>
           <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
       </div>

   </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')**

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка [Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). А так, вы выбираете `getElementById("answer-buttons")`, однако такого элемента с **id='answer-buttons'** у вас нет

Comment: Хоспаде, спасибо. Как я вообще так умудрился...

Comment: Бывает... Надо порой перегружаться )