# canvas js Как сделать прямоугольным размер клеточного автомата? cannot read properties of undefined (reading 0)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Работает только если ширина === высоте (у меня достаточно поменять в css и html)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let mas = []
let count = 0;
let timer;
const pxSize = 10
const wSize = canvas.clientWidth / pxSize
const hSize = canvas.clientHeight / pxSize
canvas.onclick = function (event) {
  let xOffset = event.offsetX
  let yOffset = event.offsetY
  let x = Math.floor(xOffset / pxSize)
  let y = Math.floor(yOffset / pxSize)
  // console.log(x, y);
  mas[y][x] = 1
  // console.log(mas);
  drawField()
}

function goLife() {
  for (let i = 0; i < hSize; i++) {
    mas[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < wSize; j++) {
      mas[i][j] = 0
    }
  }
}

goLife()

function drawField() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, wSize * pxSize, hSize * pxSize)
  for (let i = 0; i < hSize; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < wSize; j++) {
      if (mas[i][j] === 1) {
        ctx.fillRect(j * pxSize, i * pxSize, pxSize, pxSize)
      }
    }
  }
}

function startLife() {
  let a = 0
  let mas2 = []
  for (let h = 0; h < hSize; h++) {
    mas2[h] = []
    for (let w = 0; w < wSize; w++) {
      let neighbors = 0
      if (mas[fpm(h) - 1][w] === 1) neighbors++ //up
      if (mas[h][fpp(w) + 1] === 1) neighbors++ //right
      if (mas[fpp(h) + 1][w] === 1) neighbors++ //down -
      if (mas[h][fpm(w) - 1] === 1) neighbors++ //left
      if (mas[fpm(h) - 1][fpp(w) + 1] === 1) neighbors++ //up-right
      if (mas[fpp(h) + 1][fpp(w) + 1] === 1) neighbors++ //right-down -
      if (mas[fpp(h) + 1][fpm(w) - 1] === 1) neighbors++ //left-down -
      if (mas[fpm(h) - 1][fpm(w) - 1] === 1) neighbors++ //left-up
      (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3)
        ? mas2[h][w] = 1
        : mas2[h][w] = 0
      a++
    }
  }
  mas = mas2
  drawField()
  count++
  // console.log(count);
  timer = setTimeout(startLife, 2000)
}

function fpm(i) {
  if (i === 0) return hSize
  else return i
}
function fpp(i) {
  if (i === wSize - 1) return -1
  else return i
}

document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = startLife
```

```css
#c1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Life</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='c1' width="50" height="60"></canvas>
  <button id="btn">start</button>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот вопрос про ошибку [cannot read properties of undefined (reading 0)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD да я уже все пепробовал по-моему\ он как бы есть, но и нет(

Comment: На какой строке кода возникает ошибка? Смотрели, что есть в переменных перед ошибкой?

Comment: @SwaD на строке if (mas[fpp(h) + 1][w] === 1) neighbors++ //down -. перед ошибкой ничего не обычного, просто идет итерация всех w < wSize внутри h < hSize. а на последнем элементе выдает cannot read. Дебагер показывает что проблема начинается с [w] === 1. Вот тот же код, если будет легче https://codepen.io/nan-simon/pen/jOvXmZR Если закоментить эту строку то еще выдает на строках где коменты //right-down - и //left-down -

Comment: Ну так у вас всего 6 элементов в массиве, а на последнем в этом месте вы пытаетесь обратиться к 7-му элементу, который undefined и взять у него элемент с индексом 0, вот и ошибка. Добавьте перед строкой с ошибкой это `console.log(h, fpp(h) + 1, w, mas)` и все увидите

Comment: Сделал в объявлении hSize  -1, ситуацию изменило, но только в этом примере. Если делать поле больше, опять та же ошибка.

Comment: Дебажте дальше свое приложение. Вы выходите за границы массива. Смотрите, что где у вас приходит, к какому элементу обращаетесь и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо) понятно теперь что идёт лишняя итерация, осталось понять каким образом))