# Как при скролле окна добавить кнопке класс active? React Js

Tags: reactjs

Есть страница с кнопкой `<button className ="totopbtn">`

Как при скролле добавить ей класс active?

Пробовал так:

```
export default function Home() {

    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, []);
    const handleScroll = () => {
        setScroll(window.scrollY);
        document.querySelector("totopbtn").classList.add("totopbtn--active")
    };

    return (
    <button className='totopbtn' onClick={() => animateScroll.scrollToTop()}>to Top</button>
   )
```

Но так при скролле ругается, что кнопка null:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of null (reading 'classList')
> at handleScroll

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). И никогда не используйте селекторы `document.get*` и его аналоги в React проектах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: ругается потому что console.log(document.querySelector("totopbtn")) равно null

2: querySelector("(точка)totopbtn") //.totopbtn

3: вместо того что бы брать с документа можно заюзать useRef

```
export default function Home() {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScroll(window.scrollY);
      if (ref.current) {
        if (!ref.current.classList.contains('active')) {
          ref.current.classList.add('active'); // "totopbtn active"
        }
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button ref={buttonRef} className="totopbtn" onClick={() => animateScroll.scrollToTop()}>
      to Top
    </button>
  );
}
```