# Получить все свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, properties, lodash

Существует объект `obj`.
Он может являться `Object` и `Array`.
Мне нужно получить все свойства `obj`, включая возможные внутренние объекты / массивы.
Вложенность изначально не определена.

Вот пример функции, которая это делает:

```
f(obj, parentKey = '') {
      let result;
      if (_.isArray(obj)) {
        let idx = 0;
        result = _.flatMap(obj, function (obj) {
          return this.f(obj, (parentKey || '') + '[' + idx++ + ']');
        });
      }
      else if (_.isPlainObject(obj)) {
        result = _.flatMap(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
          return _.map(this.f(obj[key], key), function (subkey) {
            return (parentKey ? parentKey + '.' : '') + subkey;
          });
        }.bind(this));
      }
      else {
        result = [];
      }
      return _.concat(result, parentKey || []);
    }
```

В эту функцию передается `obj`, у которого я беру свойства.
Далее с помощью `lodash` и функции `pick` я получаю новый объект на основе другого объекта и полученных свойств из `obj` с помощью функции `f`.

Вопрос заключается в том, правильно ли функция написана?

Причина вопроса 1:
При передаче следующего аргумента `obj`

```
purchasestoplistnotice: {
purchaseinfo: {
    purchcode: '',
    comments: ''
    }
}
```

Получаю:

```
0: "purchasestoplistnotice.purchaseinfo.purchcode"
1: "purchasestoplistnotice.purchaseinfo.comments"
2: "purchasestoplistnotice.purchaseinfo"
3: "purchasestoplistnotice"
```

А не:

```
0: "purchasestoplistnotice.purchaseinfo.purchcode"
1: "purchasestoplistnotice.purchaseinfo.comments"
```

Причина вопроса 2:
При передаче `Array` в качестве `obj`. Выходит ошибка на строчке `_.flatMap(obj, ...)`:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'f')`.

Использовать функцию можно следующим образом:

```
const schema1 = ['a', 'b'];
const schema2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2};
              
const newObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    o2: {
        arr: [
            "a2",
            "b2"
        ],
        g: "asd"
    }
}

console.log(this.f(schema1));
console.log(this.f(schema2));

console.log(_.pick(newObj, this.f(schema1)));
console.log(_.pick(newObj, this.f(schema2)));
```

Примеры в Console:
Для `console.log(this.f(schema2)); и console.log(_.pick(newObj, this.f(schema2)));`

```
[
    "a",
    "b"
]
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

Для `console.log(this.f(schema1)); и console.log(_.pick(newObj, this.f(schema1)));` выпадает ошибка, указанная выше.

Comment: непонятно какой результат ты ожидаешь для указанных примеров

Comment: Ожидаю массив свойств объекта `obj`, который передается в функцию `f`.
Если у объекта `obj` существуют вложенные объекты, нужно вывести свойства вложенных объектов.
Проще говоря - крайние ноды.
Также нужно сделать и с `obj`, если он является массивом.

Comment: добавь примеры вывода для код в вопросе

Comment: если нужны только крайние ноды - то и складывай в result только когда нода крайняя

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'f')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - возможно будет полезно почитать про данную ошибку

Comment: @SwaD, в данном случае дубликат уже решает указанную ошибку

Comment: О каком дубликате речь?
Я же прикрепил вроде то, что получаю.

Comment: Добавил вывод в консоль, который я получаю.