# Как правильно сформировать данные полученные из функции doPost(e)?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код, который собирает нужные данные в переменные:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var chat_id = contents.message.chat.id;
  var text = contents.message.text;
  var reply = contents.message.reply_to_message.message_id;
  var mesid = contents.message.message_id;
  var mesdat = contents.message.date
  var name = contents.message.chat.first_name;

  ss.getSheetByName('list1').getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(contents, null, 5));
  ss.getSheetByName('list2').appendRow([chat_id, text, name, mesid, mesdat, reply]);
  
}
```

Последняя строка записывает полученные данные в гугл-таблицу. Этот код работает хорошо, если это был ответ на сообщение. Данные записываются в таблицу как и ожидалось.
Я получаю ID сообщения, на которое ответили.
Проблема в том, что если приходит просто сообщение ( а не Reply), то в таблицу ничего не записывается, и я не могу отследить на какое сообщение ответили, в таблице его просто нет.
Как можно построить сбор данных JSON так, чтоб в таблицу записывались как простые сообщения, так и ответы на другие сообщения?
Ниже приведу пример отправленных данных JSON при просто сообщении и при ответе на какое-либо сообщение.

```
"{
     ""update_id"": 659375923,
     ""message"": {
          ""message_id"": 94,
          ""from"": {
               ""id"": 477013339,
               ""is_bot"": false,
               ""first_name"": ""a"",
               ""last_name"": ""a"",
               ""username"": ""aa"",
               ""language_code"": ""ru""
          },
          ""chat"": {
               ""id"": 477013339,
               ""first_name"": ""a"",
               ""last_name"": ""a"",
               ""username"": ""aa"",
               ""type"": ""private""
          },
          ""date"": 1681410647,
          ""text"": ""111111""
     }
}"
```

А это если ответили на сообщение

```
"{
     ""update_id"": 659375924,
     ""message"": {
          ""message_id"": 95,
          ""from"": {
               ""id"": 477013339,
               ""is_bot"": false,
               ""first_name"": ""a"",
               ""last_name"": ""a"",
               ""username"": ""aa"",
               ""language_code"": ""ru""
          },
          ""chat"": {
               ""id"": 477013339,
               ""first_name"": ""a"",
               ""last_name"": ""a"",
               ""username"": ""aa"",
               ""type"": ""private""
          },
          ""date"": 1681410799,
          ""reply_to_message"": {
               ""message_id"": 83,
               ""from"": {
                    ""id"": 477013339,
                    ""is_bot"": false,
                    ""first_name"": ""a"",
                    ""last_name"": ""a"",
                    ""username"": ""aa"",
                    ""language_code"": ""ru""
               },
               ""chat"": {
                    ""id"": 477813339,
                    ""first_name"": ""a"",
                    ""last_name"": ""a"",
                    ""username"": ""aa"",
                    ""type"": ""private""
               },
               ""date"": 1681410208,
               ""text"": ""Privet""
          },
          ""text"": ""Ответное сообщ.""
     }
}"
```

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас скрипт падает на строке `var reply = contents.message.reply_to_message.message_id;` т.к. в просто сообщении нет ключа reply_to_message и вы получаете ошибку ввида [cannot read properties of undefined, reading message_id](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Поставьте проверку на данное значение

Comment: Я это понимаю, что причина именно в этом. Но главный вопрос в том, как поставить проверку на это значение, когда его нет в ответе JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы проверить наличие ключа в JSON можно воспользоваться оператором необязательной цепочки вызовов `?.`

```
var reply = contents.message.reply_to_message?.message_id;
```

Если `contents.message.reply_to_message` не существует, вернется значение **undefined**

Вы можете задать "альтернативное значение", если ключа нет оператором **||**

```
var reply = contents.message.reply_to_message?.message_id || -1;
```

В примере выше, если `contents.message.reply_to_message` не существует, будет возвращено значение **-1**