# Почему, когда просчитываю массив внутри useState, код работает, но когда выношу его создание в зависимости useEffect получаю ошибку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, useeffect, usestate

Есть такой код постраничного скроллинга:

```
export default function Home() {

    let currentOffset = 0

    const handleScroll = () => {
        
       let yPositions = []

        yPositions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('section__scroll')).map((sectionItem, index) => {

        let yPosition = sectionItem.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        yPositions.push(yPosition)
        return yPosition

    })


        currentOffset = window.scrollY
        let isScrollDown = true ? currentOffset > scroll.offset : false
        setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex, currentOffset, scroll.scrolled)


        if (currentOffset > 0) toTopBtnRef.current.classList.add("totopbtn--active")
        else toTopBtnRef.current.classList.remove("totopbtn--active")


        if (isScrollDown) {



            if (scroll.scrolled >= 50) setScroll(scroll.scrolled = 49)
            setScroll(scroll.scrolled = scroll.scrolled + 1)
            console.log(scroll.scrolled)

            if (scroll.scrolled >= 50 && scroll.currentSectionIndex < yPositions.length - 1) {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: yPositions[scroll.currentSectionIndex + 1],
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
                setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex = scroll.currentSectionIndex + 1, scroll.offset = currentOffset, scroll.scrolled = 0)
            }


        }
        else if (!isScrollDown) {
            if (scroll.scrolled < 0) setScroll(scroll.scrolled = 1)
            setScroll(scroll.scrolled = scroll.scrolled - 1)
            console.log(scroll.scrolled)
            if (scroll.scrolled <= 1 && scroll.currentSectionIndex > 0) {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: yPositions[scroll.currentSectionIndex - 1] + scroll.scrolled,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
                setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex = (scroll.currentSectionIndex - 1), scroll.offset = currentOffset, scroll.scrolled = 49)
            }
        }
    }


    let [scroll, setScroll] = useState({ currentSectionIndex: 0, offset: 0, scrolled: 0 });
    useEffect(() => {




        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);


        return () => {



            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        }



    });


    return (
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 2</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 3</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 4</section>
    )
```

Сейчас итересует массив `yPositions`. Если его заполнять в `handleScroll`, то код ошибок не выдает. Но если его вынести в компонент Home и заполнить там, а в hanleScroll передать, как зависимость:

```
    let currentOffset = 0




    let yPositions = []
    yPositions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('section__scroll')).map((sectionItem, index) => {

        let yPosition = sectionItem.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
        yPositions.push(yPosition)
        return yPosition

    })



    const handleScroll = () => {




        currentOffset = window.scrollY
        let isScrollDown = true ? currentOffset > scroll.offset : false
        setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex, currentOffset, scroll.scrolled)


        if (currentOffset > 0) toTopBtnRef.current.classList.add("totopbtn--active")
        else toTopBtnRef.current.classList.remove("totopbtn--active")


        if (isScrollDown) {



            if (scroll.scrolled >= 50) setScroll(scroll.scrolled = 49)
            setScroll(scroll.scrolled = scroll.scrolled + 1)
            console.log(scroll.scrolled)

            if (scroll.scrolled >= 50 && scroll.currentSectionIndex < yPositions.length - 1) {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: yPositions[scroll.currentSectionIndex + 1],
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
                setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex = scroll.currentSectionIndex + 1, scroll.offset = currentOffset, scroll.scrolled = 0)
            }


        }
        else if (!isScrollDown) {
            if (scroll.scrolled < 0) setScroll(scroll.scrolled = 1)
            setScroll(scroll.scrolled = scroll.scrolled - 1)
            console.log(scroll.scrolled)
            if (scroll.scrolled <= 1 && scroll.currentSectionIndex > 0) {
                window.scrollTo({
                    top: yPositions[scroll.currentSectionIndex - 1] + scroll.scrolled,
                    behavior: 'smooth'
                })
                setScroll(scroll.currentSectionIndex = (scroll.currentSectionIndex - 1), scroll.offset = currentOffset, scroll.scrolled = 49)
            }
        }
    }






    let [sectionIndex, setSectionIndex] = useState(0);
    let [scroll, setScroll] = useState({ currentSectionIndex: 0, offset: 0, scrolled: 0 });
    useEffect(() => {




        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);


        return () => {



            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        }



    }, [yPositions, currentOffset]);
    return (
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 2</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 3</section>
    <section className = 'section__scroll'>content of the section 4</section>
    )
```

То при скролле получаю ошибку в консоли:

> Home.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offset')
> at handleScroll (Home.js:76:1)

И ошибки в на странице:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: 'offset')
> и

> cannot create proparty 'scrolled' on number '2'

Comment: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offset') at handleScroll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - Проверяйте, где что и как вызывается. Скорее всего переменная **scroll** не определена. Смотрите строку Home.js:76:1