# Работая с nestjs, получил TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at AuthService.login

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, prisma

Делал авторизация пользователя в инет-магазине, регистрация проходит, jwt-token генерится и все ок. Использую insomnia для тестирования, в ней выдает 500 код, мол ошибка на сервере. При попытке войти (залогиниться) выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам id - свойство юзера

```
export type User = {
  id: number
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
  email: string
  password: string
  name: string
  phone: string
}
```

Функция логина такова:

```
    async login(dto: AuthDto) {
        const user = await this.validateUser(dto)
        const tokens = await this.issueTokens(user.id)
        console.log(user.id)

        return {
            user: this.returnUserFields(user),
            ...tokens
        }
    }
```

Юзер импортирован в этот файл, все как положено:

```
    import { User } from '@prisma/client';
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Скорее всего `const user = await this.validateUser(dto)` тут вы получаете значение **user = undefined**, а на следующей строке как раз ошибку [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o), т.к. пытаетесь выполнить **undefined.id**

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за ответ и приложенные усилия. Я не спал 30 часов уже, и... поставил лишнюю фигурную скобку в конце. Приношу извинения, и желаю Вам успехов.