# Деструктуризация поля, где первый символ число

Tags: javascript, деструктурирующее-присваивание

Подскажите, делаю запрос и мне прилетает json, я посредством деструктуризации вытаскиваю с него поля нужные и закидываю в объект

```
const {feels_like, temp} = responseDataCurrent.main
```

но там есть поле `responseDataCurrent.rain['1h']`, как записать **1h** через деструктуризацию?

```
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 41}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: 30.3694, lat: 60.0506}
main: {temp: 17.66, feels_like: 16.76, temp_min: 16.94, temp_max: 17.66, pressure: 1007, …}
weather: [{…}]
wind: {speed: 4.22, deg: 184, gust: 7.53}
rain: {1h: 0.63} //эта строчка не всегда присутствует в запросах
```

я эту строчку передаю в объект,

```
const currentObjData = {
      precipMm: responseDataCurrent.rain['1h'],
    }
```

но из за того что она отсутствует выдает ошибку Cannnot read properties of undefined, я хотел решить это через значение по умолчанию через деструктуризацию

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сам json объект, что бы было понятно, как именно он выглядит

Comment: @SwaD добавил в вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил значения по умолчанию

Answer (score 2):

При деструктуризации, вам не обязательно создавать переменные с названиями ключей, вы можете изменить их название.

т.к. имена переменных не могут начинаться с числа, нам как раз придется это сделать

```js
const x = {
  '1h': 'hour'
}

const { '1h': h1 } = x;

console.log(h1);
```

**UPD**

Если значение может не приходить, то можно воспользоваться следующими методами

Если ключ приходит, но значения нет, то можно указать значение по умолчанию для переменной

```js
const resp1 = {
  rain: { h2: 0.54 }
}
const { '1h': h1 = 1} = resp1.rain;

console.log(h1);
```

Если ключ может не приходить, или ключ равен null, то надо подменить объект, что бы избежать ошибки [Cannnot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o), для этого воспользуемся логическим оператором **или ||**

```js
const resp1 = {
  
}
const resp2 = {
  rain: null
}

const { '1h': h1 = 1} = resp1.rain || {};
const { '1h': h2 = 2} = resp2.rain || {};

console.log(h1, h2);
```

Если `resp*.rain` логически будет иметь false, то в деструктуризацию будет передан пустой объект. Ключа **1h** там нет, поэтому в переменную `h1` попадет значение по умолчанию 1.