# cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пишу ТуДу лист, добавление тасок работает, но только один раз. Подскажите в чем проблема.
Ссылка на КодПен - https://codepen.io/kwaido/pen/BaqddyE

```
const STATUS = {
  TODO: 'To Do',
  DONE: 'Done',
}

const PRIORITY = {
  HIGH: 'High',
  LOW: 'Low',
}

const list = [
  {name: 'create a post', status: 'In Progress', priority: 'low'},
  {name: 'test', status: 'Done', priority: 'high'},
]

function addTask (task) {
  list.push({'name': task})
}

function deleteTask (task) {
  let index = list.findIndex(item => item.name === task)
  list.splice(index, 1)
}

function changeStatus (task, status) {
  let index = list.findIndex(item => item.name === task)
  switch (status) {
    case STATUS.TODO: 
    list[index].status = STATUS.TODO
    break
    case STATUS.DONE: 
    list[index].status = STATUS.DONE
    break
  }
}

const taskName   = document.querySelectorAll('.add-input');
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.plus');
const delTaskBtn = document.querySelector('.delete-task');
const checkbox   = document.querySelector('.checkbox');
const highTasks  = document.querySelector('.high-tasks');
const lowTasks   = document.querySelector('.low-tasks');


for (let e of addTaskBtn) {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    // Создаем элементы
    const divTask = document.createElement('div');
    const spanCheckbox = document.createElement('span');
    const spanTaskText = document.createElement('span');
    const spanDeleteTask = document.createElement('span');

    // Формируем структуру и вешаем стили
    divTask.appendChild(spanCheckbox).classList.add('checkbox');
    divTask.appendChild(spanTaskText).classList.add('task-text');
    divTask.appendChild(spanDeleteTask).classList.add('delete-task');
    divTask.classList.add('task');

    // Наполняем элементы
    spanDeleteTask.innerText = '+'
    spanTaskText.innerText = e.previousElementSibling.value // Ошибка тут!!!!!!!!!!
    console.log(e.previousElementSibling.value);
    // Вешаем обработчики кнопок
    del(spanDeleteTask)
    check(spanCheckbox)

    // Добавляем таску в DOM
    if (e.previousElementSibling.value) {
      e.classList.contains('high-tasks') ? highTasks.appendChild(divTask) :
      lowTasks.appendChild(divTask);
    }
    // Добавляем таску в лист
    // addTask(e.previousElementSibling.value)

    // Обнуляем инпуты
    // e.previousElementSibling.value = '';
    
    // Логирование
    for (e of list) {
      console.log(e);
    }

  });
};

// Удаление таски из DOM
function del (e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  });

};
// Пометка выполненной таски DOM
function check (e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.contains('checkbox-checked') ? e.target.classList.remove('checkbox-checked') : 
    e.target.classList.add('checkbox-checked');
  });
};
```

Comment: [Как понять и исправить ошибку cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)