# Cannot read properties of undefined при переходе между страницами

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть две функции, которые выводят таблицы, первая вызывается в одном файле, вторая во втором, при этом если в таблице первой функции чекбоксы активны, она передает значение в таблицу второй функции. Проблема в том, что при переходе между страницами, данные видимо стираются и выдает ошибку:

> **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { MdArrowDropUp, MdArrowDropDown } from 'react-icons/md'
import axios from 'axios';

export const API_URL = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull';
export const INTERVAL_TIME = 1000;
export const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'cryptoData';

export function GET_TOP_100() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCoins, setSelectedCoins] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const dataFromStorage = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
        if (dataFromStorage) {
          setData(JSON.parse(dataFromStorage));
        } else {
          fetchData();
        }
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          fetchData();
        }, INTERVAL_TIME);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);
    
      const fetchData = () => {
        axios.get(API_URL, {
          params: {
            limit: 100,
            tsym: 'USD'
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.Data;
          setData(data);
          localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      };
    
      const selectedCoinIds = useMemo(() => {
        return selectedCoins.map((coin) => coin.CoinInfo.Id);
      }, [selectedCoins]);
    
      const handleCheckboxChange = (coin) => {
        const coinIndex = selectedCoins.findIndex(
          (selectedCoin) => selectedCoin.CoinInfo.Id === coin.CoinInfo.Id
        );
        if (coinIndex === -1) {
          setSelectedCoins([...selectedCoins, coin]);
        } else {
          setSelectedCoins([
            ...selectedCoins.slice(0, coinIndex),
            ...selectedCoins.slice(coinIndex + 1),
          ]);
        }
      };

      const renderTable = () => {
        return (
          <div className='scrollable'>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Check</th>
                  <th>Rank</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Symbol</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>1h %</th>
                  <th>24h %</th>
                  <th>Market Cap</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {data.map((coin, index) => (
                <tr key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
                  <td>
                  <input
                      type='checkbox'
                      className='checkbox-coin'
                      checked={selectedCoinIds.includes(coin.CoinInfo.Id)}
                      onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(coin)}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>
                      <img src={`https://www.cryptocompare.com${coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl}`} alt={coin.CoinInfo.FullName} className='image-tokens'/>
                      {coin.CoinInfo.FullName}
                    </td>
                    <td>{coin.CoinInfo.Name}</td>
                    <td>{coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</td>
                    <td style={{ color: coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR >= 0 ? '#00FA9A' : '#DC143C' }}>
                    {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR}% 
                    {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR >= 0 ? <MdArrowDropUp /> : <MdArrowDropDown />}
                  </td>
                  <td style={{ color: coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR >= 0 ? '#00FA9A' : '#DC143C' }}>
                    {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}% 
                    {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR >= 0 ? <MdArrowDropUp /> : <MdArrowDropDown />}
                  </td>
                    <td>{coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      };
      
      return (
        <div>
            {data.length > 0 ? renderTable() : <p className='loading'>Loading...</p>}
        </div>
      )
}

export function GET_SELECTION_COIN({ selectedCoins, handleCheckboxChange }) {
    const selectedCoinIds = useMemo(() => {
      return selectedCoins.map((coin) => coin.CoinInfo.Id);
    }, [selectedCoins]);
    
      const renderTable = () => {
        return (
          <div className='scrollable'>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Check</th>
                  <th>Rank</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Symbol</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>1h %</th>
                  <th>24h %</th>
                  <th>Market Cap</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {selectedCoins.map((coin, index) => (
                  <tr key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
                    <td>
                      <input
                        type='checkbox'
                        className='checkbox-coin'
                        checked={selectedCoinIds.includes(coin.CoinInfo.Id)}
                        onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(coin)}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>
                      <img
                        src={`https://www.cryptocompare.com${coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl}`}
                        alt={coin.CoinInfo.FullName}
                        className='image-tokens'
                      />
                      {coin.CoinInfo.FullName}
                    </td>
                    <td>{coin.CoinInfo.Name}</td>
                    <td>{coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</td>
                    <td
                      style={{
                        color:
                          coin.DISPLAY &&
                          coin.DISPLAY.USD &&
                          coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR >= 0
                            ? '#00FA9A'
                            : '#DC143C',
                      }}
                    >
                      {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR}%
                      {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR >= 0 ? (
                        <MdArrowDropUp />
                      ) : (
                        <MdArrowDropDown />
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td
                      style={{
                        color:
                          coin.DISPLAY &&
                          coin.DISPLAY.USD &&
                          coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR >= 0
                            ? '#00FA9A'
                            : '#DC143C',
                      }}
                    >
                      {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR}%
                      {coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEPCT24HOUR >= 0 ? (
                        <MdArrowDropUp />
                      ) : (
                        <MdArrowDropDown />
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>{coin.DISPLAY && coin.DISPLAY.USD && coin.DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      };
    
      return (
          <div>{selectedCoins.length > 0 ? renderTable() : <p>No selected coins</p>}</div>
      ) 
  }
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at http://localhost:3000/main.c2d86fca4fce672f8a82.hot-update.js:276:26
    at mountMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26930:23)
    at Object.useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27315:20)
    at useMemo (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145090:25)
    at GET_SELECTION_COIN (http://localhost:3000/main.c2d86fca4fce672f8a82.hot-update.js:275:73)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26158:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29444:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30740:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15750:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15794:20)
```

Подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: Вы не указали, как вы вызываете GET_SELECTION_COIN, однако, при первом рендеринге `selectedCoins` будет **undefined**, поэтому и получаете ошибку [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/). В определении фукнции добавьте значение по умолчанию `function GET_SELECTION_COIN({ selectedCoins = [], handleCheckboxChange })` или переменную selectedCoins вынесите в стейт компонента

Comment: @SwaD из-за такой глупой ошибки так долго парился, спасибо