# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storage') в react-yandex-map 2.1

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

я хочу создать кнопку, которая будет показывается в зависимости от пользователя, который открыл ее. Шаблон для балунов я пишу в html, поэтому я не могу указать параметр `disable=false`. Он его просто не будет видеть. `document.getElementById("buttun2").disabled = false;` тоже не помогает. Я попытался решить проблему с помощью `ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass` но когда я пытаюсь прикрепит его к ключу с помощью `ymaps.layout.storage.add` он выкидывает ошибку

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storage')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storage')
```

Вот полный код, где я это использую. Пусть вас не смущает отсутствующие части кода, т.к. оттуда были вырезаны ненужные куски. Прошу любой подсказки а то я уже отчаялся. Спасибо!

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, Clusterer , Button,Placemark } from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps';
import "../css/ballon.css"
import Header from "./Header";
import {Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
const mapState = {
    center: [55.7924886417031, 49.12233672582469],
    zoom: 9
};

const YMap = () => {

    const placemarkRef = React.useRef(null);
    const mapRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [address, SetAddress] = React.useState("");
    const [count, setValue] = useState(0);
    const [canAddPlacemark, checkAddPlacemark] = useState(false);
    const [oldRegionName, addOldRegionName] = useState();
    const [oldRegion, addOldRegion] = useState();
    const [ymaps, setYmaps] = useState(React.useRef(null));
    const [openedDescription, openDescription] = useState(null);
    const [clusterBalloon, setClusterBalloon] = useState(null);

      const closeDescription = () => {
        setClusterBalloon(null);
        openDescription(null);
      };
    const createPlacemark = (coords) => {
        return new ymaps.current.Placemark(
            coords,
            {
                iconCaption: "loading.."
            },
            {
                preset: "islands#violetDotIconWithCaption",
                draggable: true
            }
        );
    };
    let regionName = "";
    const getAddress = async (coords) => {
        placemarkRef.current.properties.set("iconCaption", "loading..");
        await  ymaps.current.geocode(coords).then((res) => {
                const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                const newAddress = [
                    firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length
                        ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities()
                        : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                    firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                ]
                    .filter(Boolean)
                    .join(", ");

                SetAddress(newAddress);

                placemarkRef.current.properties.set({
                    iconCaption: newAddress,
                    balloonContent: '     <div> <input type="button" onClick={() => { openDescription(index);}} value="Подробнее"/> </div>'
                });
                regionName =firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()[0];
            })
    };
    const markers = [ {
        "coord": "55.79424260833246,49.68814042729016",
        "id": 1,
        "author": "Abdul",
        },
        {
            "coord": "55.62832515119459, 49.11135820072768",
            "id": 2,
            "author": "Abdul",
        },
        {
            "coord": "55.910118447321, 48.70761064213393",
            "id": 3,
            "author": "Abdul",
        }
    ]
    const addMarkers = () =>{


        markers.forEach(marker => {
            var balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                '<div class="cd-quick-view">' +
                '<div class="cd-slider-wrapper">' +
                '<ul class="cd-slider">' +
                '</ul>' +
                '<li><img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/616/389/png-transparent-isolated-animal-leopard-safari-wildlife-africa.png" width="200" height="100"></li>' +
                '<ul class="cd-slider-navigation">' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="cd-item-info">' +
                '<h2>Produt Title</h2>' +
                `<p>Автор метки: ${marker.author}</p>` +
                `<p>Инфа о воздухе: пока нет</p>` +
                '<ul class="cd-item-action">' +
                '<li>' +
                '<button id="buttun1" class="add-to-cart1" disabled>Add to cart</button>' +
                '<button id="buttun2" class="add-to-cart2">Add to cart</button>' +
                '<button id="buttun3" class="add-to-cart3">Add to cart</button>' +
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            );

            ymaps.layout.storage.add('tinko#officeslayout', balloonContentLayout);
        var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(marker.coord.split(','), {
            balloonHeader: 'Заголовок балуна',
            // balloonContent:balloonContentLayout,
            balloonContentBodyLayout:'tinko#officeslayout',
            balloonFooter: 'Футер балуна'
        },{
            balloonShadow: true,
            // balloonLayout: balloonContentBody,
            // Запретим замену обычного балуна на балун-панель.
            // Если не указывать эту опцию, на картах маленького размера откроется балун-панель.
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 1,
            hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
        });
        // Добавим метку на карту.
        mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(placemark);
            // document.getElementById("buttun2").disabled = false;
            // document.getElementById("buttun2").setAttribute('disabled','true')
        });
    }
    const onMapClick = (e) => {
        var objectId = e.get('id')
        console.log(objectId)
        if (canAddPlacemark){
            let objectManager = new ymaps.current.ObjectManager();
            objectManager.options.set('geoObjectInteractivityModel', 'default#transparent');
                const coords = e.get("coords");
                if (placemarkRef.current) {
                placemarkRef.current.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
            } else {
                placemarkRef.current = createPlacemark(coords);
                mapRef.current.geoObjects.add(placemarkRef.current);
                placemarkRef.current.events.add("dragend", function () {
                    getAddress(placemarkRef.current.geometry.getCoordinates());
                });
            }
            getAddress(coords);
        }
    };


    function sayHello() {
        setValue(count+1);
        if(count % 2 != 0){
            checkAddPlacemark(canAddPlacemark => !canAddPlacemark)
        }
        else{
            checkAddPlacemark(canAddPlacemark => !canAddPlacemark)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <YMaps query={{
                // load: "package.full" ,
                apikey: "106e4ebf-abbc-41b9-9230-adfbc64f15d9" }}>
                <Map defaultState={{
                    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                    zoom: 9
                }}
                     modules={["Clusterer","Polygon","GeoObject","geoQuery","control.ZoomControl", "control.FullscreenControl","Placemark", "geocode",
                         "geoObject.addon.balloon","borders", "ObjectManager",'geoObject.addon.balloon','clusterer.addon.balloon',
                         'templateLayoutFactory']}
                     style={{
                         flex: 2,
                         height: "calc(100vh - 57px)"
                     }}
                     onClick={onMapClick}
                     instanceRef={mapRef}
                     onLoad={ymaps => setYmaps(ymaps)}
                     state={mapState}
                >
                    <Button  onClick={sayHello} data={{ content: 'Button' }} options={{ float: 'right' }} />
                    <Button  onClick={addMarkers} data={{ content: 'Вывод маркеров' }} options={{ float: 'right' }} />
                </Map>
                <Modal show={show2} onHide={handleClose2}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton className="backcolorBlack">
                        <Modal.Title>Edit Message</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body className="backcolorBlack">
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>[Full Name]:</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="User Full Name..." />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label> Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email..."
                                      />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer className="backcolorBlack">
                        <Button variant="danger" onClick={handleClose2}>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
                            console.log("friend To Edit");
                            handleClose2();
                        }}>
                            Update
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </YMaps>
        </div>

    )
}

export default YMap;
```

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: А react-yandex-map вообще поддерживает такой функционал? Может в первую очередь у его разработчиков уточнить?