# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript

Создаю динамические блоки внутри которых есть кнопка, при которой нужно чтоб блок удалялся, с толкнулся с такой проблемой. Событие не вещается из за того что еще не создан блок, как можно решить данную проблему?

```
btnAddNotes.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    let bodyNotes = document.querySelector('.notes__body')
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let inputTitle = document.querySelector('.modal__title').value
    let inputText = document.querySelector('.modal__text').value
    newDiv.innerHTML = `
    <div class="notes__content">
        <div id="notes" class="remove__notes">&times</div>
        <h1>${inputTitle}</h1>
        <span>${inputText}</span>
    </div>`;
    bodyNotes.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newDiv);
    closeModal()
})
```

Ниже код который вызывает ошибку

```
Класс remove__notes появляется когда создается блок, потому что это кнопка внутри созданного блока
btnRemoveNotes = document.querySelector('.remove__notes')
btnRemoveNotes.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    console.log('Win')
}
```

Comment: После добавления блока, добавлять слушатель. Покажите кусок кода, как вы создаете слушатель, как и где создаете блоки

Comment: @SwaD Добавил код

Comment: У вас, судя по ошибке, `btnAddNotes` -> **null**. Как и что вы сохраняете в эту переменную? Почитайте про природу ошибки [Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o), возможно станет понятней, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: @SwaD У меня ошибка когда я пишу новое событие для кнопки внутри динамического блока, я пишу новую переменную btnRemoveNotes = document.querySelector('.remove__notes') ей даю событие и оно пишет ошибку

Comment: А с какой тогда целью представлен кусок кода, который только создает блок, но в нем нет ошибки? Покажите код, который приводит к ошибке. P.S. Вы же знаете, что `querySelector` вернет первый попавшийся элемент?

Comment: @SwaD Добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо создавать обработчик нажатия кнопки вместе с созданием самого блока.

Ниже пример такой реализации. При нажатии на кнопку, будет добавлен блок, кнопка удаления и на кнопке уже будет висеть слушатель, который удаляет свой блок

```js
const btnAddNotes = document.getElementById('btn');
btnAddNotes.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    let bodyNotes = document.querySelector('.notes__body')
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let inputTitle = document.querySelector('.modal__title').value
    let inputText = document.querySelector('.modal__text').value
    // Создаем кнопку
    const rmBtn = document.createElement("div");
    rmBtn.innerHTML = `&times`;
    rmBtn.classList = 'remove__notes'
    rmBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { // И обработчик
      newDiv.remove();
    });
    // Контейнер с данными
    const conteiner = document.createElement("div");
    conteiner.classList.add('notes__content');
    //Заголовок
    const h = document.createElement('h1');
    h.innerText = inputTitle;
    // Текст
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = inputText;
    // Добавляем кнопку и текст в контейнер
    conteiner.append(rmBtn);
    conteiner.append(h);
    conteiner.append(span);
    // Вставляем в newDiv
    newDiv.append(conteiner);
    bodyNotes.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', newDiv);
    //closeModal()
})
```

```html
<div class='notes__body'></div>
title: <input class='modal__title'><br/>
text: <input class='modal__text'><br />
<button id='btn'>add</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!