# Как создать двух ботов в одном исполняемом файле JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Обьясняю ситуацию: у меня есть один бот который напрямую подключен к игровому серверу, и есть второй бот который подключен к сообществу вк, мне нужно этих ботов засунуть в один файл ради удобства управления (частный случай), сервер стоит на NodeJS, возможность использовать express соответственно.
первой попыткой законнектить работу этих ботов был следующий исполняемый код:
код первого бота:

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { Vec3 } = require('vec3')

const readline = require('readline')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout
})


if (process.argv.length < 2 || process.argv.length > 4) {
  console.log('Usage : node chatterbot.js <host> <port>')
  process.exit(1)
}

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: process.argv[2],
  port: parseInt(process.argv[3]),
  username: 'name',
  password: 'pass'
})
```

код второго бота, с элементом взаимодействия первого бота:

```
const { VK } = require('vk-io');
const { HearManager} = require('@vk-io/hear');

const vk = new VK({
   token: 'mytoken'
})
const vbot = new HearManager()

vbot.updates.on('message_new', bot.middleware)

vbot.hear(/test/i, msg => {
  bot.chat('работает')
})
```

на первый взгляд выглядит просто: при отправке сообщения в сообщество ВК с ботом, второй бот бы отправлял в игровой чат сообщение "Работает", но увы я получаю ошибку что "on" в строке "vbot.updates.on('message_new', bot.middleware)" undefined, единственное что приходит в голову так возможно, что константу vbot не воспринимает за бота из за буквы v, которую я добавил дабы избежать дубликации с константой первого бота.

Полный текст ошибки, которая возникает при запуске:

---

```
vbot.updates.on('message_new', bot.middleware)
             ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
```

---

помогите пж, а то лень писать запросы для общения двух ботов через json обьекты((

Comment: Дополните вопрос полным текстом ошибки, которая возникает

Comment: дополнил, это поможет вам Помочь мне?)

Comment: Почитайте про [ошику Cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Ответ поможет вам ее исправить. Если кратко, то у переменной `vbot` нет метода `updates`. Посмотрите, что вообще лежит в этой переменной.