# Что может быть не так в коде? (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add'))

Tags: javascript

У меня есть блок с id="nav" в котором находятся ещё 2 блока с class="header".
Во время события scroll, я выдаю объектам класс moveup или movedown(зависит от pageYOffset).
Я пробовал HtmlCollection перевести в Array, в следствии чего ничего не произошло.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() =>{
  const header = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByClassName("header");
  function onScroll(){
    if(pageYOffset >= 250){
      for(let i = 0; i < header.length; i++){
        let element = header[i];
        element.ClassList.add("moveup");
        element.ClassList.remove("movedown");
      }
    }else{
      for(let i = 0; i < header.length; i++){
        let element = header[i];
        element.сlassList.add("movedown");
        element.ClassList.remove("moveup");
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
});
```

Comment: Почитайте про [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Вы опечатались. Надо `classList` а у вас `ClassList`. Т.е. буква С должна быть маленькой

Comment: @SwaD проблема почти ушла, но там, где не было опечатки, осталась ошибка.

Comment: Если ошибка та же, то проверяйте, чему у вас равно значение переменной **element**

Comment: Я проверил значение переменной **element** и **element.classList**. Все хорошо.

Comment: Тогда ошибки, указанной выше быть не может, если element.classList существует

Comment: Я решил переписать строчку заново и код начал работать. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: `element.сlassList.add("movedown");` - здесь буква `с` кириллица.