# массив в хранилище не успевает обновится в следствии чего консоль выводит undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

я делаю пагинацию по выводу книг на странице, api не дает получить вест массив книг сразу, поэтому при переходе на страницу приходится делать новый запрос к api с измененным индексом начала массива

при первом запросе все срабатывает, ибо как я понял я сразу вставляю в компонент из запроса, а не из хранилища, но при пагинации массив не успевает сохранять, не понимаю как исправить

**SearchForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './SearchForm.css'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { ArrayOfItemsFound } from '../store/slices/SearcherSlice'
import { SearchValue } from '../store/slices/PaginatorSlice'

const SearchForm = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [bookData, setData] = useState([]);

  const searchBook=(evt)=>{
    if(evt.key==="Enter")
    {
      axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+ search +'&key=SECRET_KEY'+'&maxResults=30')
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data)
        dispatch(SearchValue(search))
        dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Ошибка при запросе к API:', error);
      });

    }

  }


  return (
    <>
      <div className='search-form'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='search-form-content'>
            <div className='search-form'>
              <div className='search-form-elem flex flex-sb bg-white'>
                <input type="text" className='form-control' placeholder='Name of book...'
                  value={search} 
                  onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                  onKeyUp={searchBook}/>
                <button className='flex flex-c'>
                  <FaSearch className='text-light-black' size={28} />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </>
  )
}

export default SearchForm
```

**BookList.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './BookList.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Book from './Book';
import Pagination from '../Pagination/Pagination';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ArrayOfItemsFound } from '../store/slices/SearcherSlice'

const BookList = () => {
  const {totalItems, items} = useSelector(state => state.searcher.value)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [booksPerPage] = useState(30)

  const searchValue = useSelector(state => state.paginator.value)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const paginate = pageNumer => setCurrentPage(pageNumer)

  const SearchBookForPage = () => {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='+ searchValue +'&key=SECRET_KEY'+'&maxResults=30'+'&startIndex=' + currentPage * 30)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(ArrayOfItemsFound(response.data.items))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Ошибка при запросе к API:', error);
    });
  }

        return (
          <div className='BookList'>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="BookList-content flex flex-column">
                <div className="BookList-amountOfResults text-black">
                  Found {totalItems} results
                </div>
                <div className="BookList-books grid">
                  <Book />
                  {console.log(items)}
                </div>
                <div className="BookList-pagination">
                  <Pagination 
                    SearchBookForPage = {SearchBookForPage}
                    booksPerPage = {booksPerPage}
                    totalBooks = {totalItems}
                    paginate = {paginate}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
}

export default BookList
```

**Pagination.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Pagination.css'

const Pagination = ({ booksPerPage, totalBooks, paginate, SearchBookForPage }) => {

  const pageNumbers = []

  for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalBooks / booksPerPage); i++ ) {
    pageNumbers.push(i)
  }


  return (
    <div className="Pagination">
        {
          pageNumbers.map(number => (
            <a href="!#" className="pagination-a" 
              onClick={() => {
                paginate(number)
                SearchBookForPage()
              }}
            >
              {number}
            </a>
          ))
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

**Book.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Book.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Book = () => {
  const {items} = useSelector(state => state.searcher.value)
  return (
    <>
      {
        items.map((item) =>{
          let bookPicture = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks && item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;
          let bookTitle = item.volumeInfo.title
          let bookAuthor = item.volumeInfo.authors
          let bookCategories = item.volumeInfo.categories
          return(
            <>
              <div className='book'>
                  <div className='book-content flex flex-column '>
                    <div className="book-img">
                      <img src={bookPicture} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <p className='book-category text-center '>{bookCategories}</p>
                    <h3 className='book-tittle fs-16 text-center'>{bookTitle}</h3>
                    <p className='book-autor text-center text-light-black'>{bookAuthor}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Book
```

**SearcherSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const searcherSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'searcher',
  initialState: {
    value: {
      totalItems: '0',
      items: []
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    ArrayOfItemsFound: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { ArrayOfItemsFound } = searcherSlice.actions
```

**PaginatorSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const paginatorSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'paginator',
  initialState: {
    value: ''
  },
  reducers: {
    SearchValue: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { SearchValue } = paginatorSlice.actions

export default paginatorSlice.reducer
export default searcherSlice.reducer
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import searcherReducer from './slices/SearcherSlice';
import paginatorReducer from './slices/PaginatorSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    searcher: searcherReducer,
    paginator: paginatorReducer
  }
})
```

**Ошибка**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Book (Book.jsx:8:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Comment: А теперь поясните, в каком компоненте, при каком запросе и где именно вы получаете undefined

Comment: ну как я понял, я написал пагинацию которая при клике на страницу запрашивает новые массив от api и она должна useSelector - ом забраться в компоненте Book, но пишет undefined

Comment: добавил ошибку в вопросе

Comment: Переменная **items** на момент первого рендера не определена. Проверяйте, что возвращает useSelector и на сколько верный путь к state. Можно сделать проверку перед рендером, что items существует. [Суть ошибки Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: так я понял, что я передавал в компоненте BookList именно items а не все что дает мне api, но теперь проблема другая почему то при переходе на другую страницу у меня растет значение всех данных запроса

Comment: я теперь даже не понимаю как правильно тут сформулировать вопрос внятный)

Comment: Вот и я не понимаю фразы *растет значение всех данных запроса*

Comment: ну вообщем, изначально когда я ввожу поисковой запрос выводится общее количество найденных книг например 500, по ним снизу пишется пагинация например 20 страниц и выводятся эти книги на страниуе 30 шт. Но когда я жму на другую страницу страниц пагинации становится что-то около 100, всего найденных результатов около 2000, и так далее. Хотя я проверяю в коносле массив книг он 30 книг которые на странице. Поэтому я и не понимаю о чем именно спросить в этом моменте

Comment: может у вас есть какие-то идеи, я в тупике(