# Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, axios, prototype

Мне нужна Ваша помощь в поиске ошибки.

**server.js**

```
// import axios from 'axios';
    
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.post('/send-message', (req, expressRes) => {
      // Переименовано expressRes
      const { name, tel, comment } = req.body;
      const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
      const CHAT_ID = process.env.CHAT_ID;
      const URL_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage`;
    
      const message =
        `<b>Заявка с сайта!</b>\n` +
        `<b>Отправитель: </b> ${name}\n` +
        `<b>Телефон: </b> ${tel}\n` +
        `<b>Имя пользователя: </b> ${comment}`;
    
      axios
        .post(URL_API, {
          chat_id: CHAT_ID,
          parse_mode: 'html',
          text: message,
        })
        .then(_axiosRes => {
          // Переименовано res в axiosRes
          expressRes.status(200).json({ message: 'Сообщение отправлено!' });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          expressRes
            .status(500)
            .json({ message: 'Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения' });
        });
    });
    
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Сервер запущен на порту ${PORT}`);
    });
```

**tg.js**

```
// import axios from 'axios';

    const success = document.getElementById('success');
    
    document.getElementById('tg-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      let name = this.name.value;
      let tel = this.tel.value;
      let comment = this.comment.value;
    
      axios
        .post('/send-message', { name, tel, comment })
        .then(res => {
          console.log('Статус ответа:', res.status);
          console.log('Данные ответа:', res.data);
    
          this.name.value = '';
          this.tel.value = '';
          this.comment.value = '';
          success.innerHTML = 'Сообщение отправлено!';
          success.style.display = 'block';
        })
    
        .catch(err => {
          console.warn(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log('Отправили!');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Указанная ошибка и ваш код - разное. В представленном коде такой ошибки быть не может. Почитайте про ошибку [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD я вообще не понимаю где мне искать ошибку (((

Comment: У вас в оригинале ошибки должно быть указано: имя файла, # строки кода и даже номер позиции символа, где ошибка возникла. + поищите слово prototype

Comment: @SwaD index.9462a21a.js:61716 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at 9mlRX.f03d0cf7d09c1c27 (index.9462a21a.js:61716:49)
at newRequire (index.9462a21a.js:71:24)
at localRequire (index.9462a21a.js:84:35)
at hJdSW.94ac0797b21fcf7e (index.9462a21a.js:52191:11)
at newRequire (index.9462a21a.js:71:24)
at localRequire (index.9462a21a.js:84:35)
at nvDge.589cf1a941825cde (index.9462a21a.js:52172:18)
at newRequire (index.9462a21a.js:71:24)
at localRequire (index.9462a21a.js:84:35)
at 2KDPO.9420b6a410cb15e (index.9462a21a.js:580:17)

Comment: это с консоли оригинал

Comment: Ну судя по всему, у вас ошибка на клиенте. Попробуйте отследить, когда она возникает. Так же можно ткнуть на указанные файлы и посмотреть, что там творится. Вспоминайте, что вы делали, что добавляли в код, после чего вылезла эта ошибка. В том куске кода, что представлен здесь, ошибки нет. Ваш код с ошибкой будет выглядеть как то так: `object.prototype.somevalue` где `object` это какой то объект(подразумевается), но он имеет значение **undefined**

Comment: @SwaD Спасибо. Буду искать