# колбэк функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции, callback

```
person1 = {
  name: 'pavel',
  age: 16
}

function plusAge(person){
  console.log('foo')
  return person.age += 1
}

plusAge(person1)
```

При запуске этого кода все работает без пререканий.

Но если стартануть его с колбэк функцией при помощи bind,:

```
person1 = {
  name: 'pavel',
  age: 16
}

function plusAge(person){
  console.log('foo')
  return person.age += 1
}

setTimeout(plusAge.bind(person1), 1000)
```

...то выдает вот такую ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем причина?

Comment: `bind()` это не колбэк функция, а метод, возвращающий новую фукнцию. Первый параметр - контекст вызова, а не передаваемый аргумент. Читаем про [bind](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind), и про ошибку [Cannot read property on undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, немного поподробнее объяснить, как этот метод работает? Просто я скорее новичок в js

Comment: Зачем он вам, этот метод? Какое поведение вы ожидаете или что изучаете?

Comment: @SwaD изучаю callback функции в JS, ищу способ передавать аргумент в функцию, являющуюся аргументом другой функции. (Извиняюсь, если тупо объясняю, самому слух режет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [bind()](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind) возвращает новую функцию, в которой зафиксирован контекст выполнения, а так же аргументы фукнции, если они были переданы.

```js
function simpleFunction(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log('this', this);
  console.log('args', arg1, arg2);
}

const myThis = {
  variable: 'I`m'
}
// Исходная фукнция
simpleFunction('1', '2');

// Зафиксировали контекст
const funcThis = simpleFunction.bind(myThis);
funcThis('2', '3'); // Передаем только аргументы

// Зафиксировали контекст и первый аргумент
const funcOne = simpleFunction.bind(myThis, '4');
funcOne('5'); // Передаем только 2й агрумент

// Зафиксировали контекст и 2 аргумента
const funcTwo = simpleFunction.bind(myThis, '6', '7');
funcTwo(); // Ничего не передаем, все зафиксировано
```

P.S. Первый вывод this очень длинный, т.к. это будет объект window

Теперь, обладая знаниями метода **bind()**, можно поправить ваш код:

```js
const person1 = {
  name: 'pavel',
  age: 16
}

function plusAge(person){
  console.log(person.age += 1);
}
// Первый аргумент в bind не передаем, т.к. он не нужен функции
setTimeout(plusAge.bind(null, person1), 1000);
```

Другой пример:
Вызываем фукнцию plusAndCall, в которую передаем колбэк фукнцию displayAge и объект.
После выполнения нужных нам расчетов в фукнции plusAndCall, будет вызвана колбэк-фукнция displayAge, в которую, в качестве аргумента будет передан посчитанный age:

```js
const person1 = {
  name: 'pavel',
  age: 16
}

function plusAndCall(callBackFunction, object) {
  object.age += 1;
  callBackFunction(object.age);
}

function displayAge(age) {
  console.log(`Age is ${age}`);
}

plusAndCall(displayAge, person1);
```