# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'frontierSign')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tiktok

```
import re

from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

msToken = [
    '********',
]
async def fetch_video_max_view(api: TikTokApi, username: str,
                               video_count: int,
                               comment: str) \
        -> list[tuple[str, str, int, str]]:
    """Fetch max views of videos for a TikTok user."""
    result = []
    async for video in api.user(username=username).videos(count=video_count):
        video_stats = video.stats['playCount']
        view = video_stats
        video_url = video.id
        result.append((username, video_url, view, comment))
        await asyncio.sleep(2.5)
    return result
async def info_videos(file_url: str,
                      video_count: int):
    """Fetch and print the max views of videos for TikTok
     users listed in a file.

    Args:
        file_url (str): Path to the file containing TikTok usernames
         or profile links.
        video_count (int): Number of videos to fetch for each user.

    Returns:
        list
    """
    if not file_url:
        print('Выберите файл с аккаунтами!')
        raise FileExistsError(file_url)

    async with (TikTokApi() as api):

        await api.create_sessions(ms_tokens=msToken,
                                  num_sessions=1, sleep_after=3)
        result = []
        with open(file_url, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                line = line.strip()
                match = re.search(r'@([^/]+)', line)

                if match:
                    params = match.group(1).split('#')
                    username = params[0].strip()
                    comment = params[1].strip() if len(params) > 1 else ''

                else:
                    params = line.split('#')
                    username = params[0].strip()
                    comment = params[1].strip() if len(params) > 1 else ''

                try:
                    view_all = await fetch_video_max_view(api=api,
                                                          username=username,
                                                          comment=comment,
                                                          video_count=video_count)
                    result.extend(view_all)
                except Exception as e:
                    return e

        return sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

print(asyncio.run(info_videos('temp_uploads/test.txt', 1)))
```

Код который возможно и выдаёт эту ошибку:

```
    async def generate_x_bogus(self, url: str, **kwargs):
        """Generate the X-Bogus header for a url"""
        _, session = self._get_session(**kwargs)
        result = await session.page.evaluate(
            f'() => {{ return window.byted_acrawler.frontierSign("{url}") }}'
        )
        return result
```

Comment: Это полный стэк трейс ошибки? Вообще, судя по тексту, ошибка 1 в 1 похожа на [ошибку javaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Похоже, что на фронте что то происходит или туда передается вместо значения undefined, у которого потом пытаются взять свойство frontierSign

Comment: @SwaD да, эток полный трейс ошибки. Просто странно что она может появлятся, а можеи нет. Через раз короче, и не знаю как решить эту проблему.

Comment: @SwaD с помощью debug режима нашел код который может быть связан с этой ошибкой.     
    async def generate_x_bogus(self, url: str, **kwargs):
        """Generate the X-Bogus header for a url"""
        _, session = self._get_session(**kwargs)
        result = await session.page.evaluate(
            f'() => {{ return window.byted_acrawler.frontierSign("{url}") }}'
        )
        return result

Comment: Добавьте это в сам вопрос

Comment: @SwaD добавил код

Comment: `window` глобальный объект браузера. Ошибка говорит, что у него нет ключа byted_acrawler. Этот ключ либо в другом месте задается по условию, которое не отрабатывает, либо удаляется(суть: в момент вызова, ключа нет). Копайте в эту сторону, по какой причине и в каких именно случаях происходит ошибка. Ищите, кто и когда данный ключ записывает в браузер пользователю(может и удаляет по каким то условиям - перезапуск браузера - f5 - точно удалит ключ, если по умолчанию, при старте, он не добавляется).

Comment: @SwaD так а почему один раз без ошибок, а второй раз уже есть ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка появляется, потому что ключа **byted_acrawler** нет в браузерном объекте **window**. Почему и кто его удаляет ¯\\(ツ)/¯ надо ковырять код и отслеживать всю цепочку последовательностей, приводящих к ошибке

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Я заметил такую странную штуку, если я указываю msToken то ошибка появляется, если msToken нету, всё хорощо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть PR насчет этого, поищите в issues. Там упоминется lazy-loading еще, и если добавить в код перед этим вызовом:

```
await session.page.wait_for_function("window.byted_acrawler !== undefined")
```

то вроде как конкретно эта ошибка не возникает.

Но есть другая проблема: этот токен потом не работает:) Код сайта делает длиной 28, а функция выдает длиной 16.

Я подозреваю, что мы ее неправильно запускаем, ибо код обновился:( Я вижу первый аргумент 413, потом только параметры запроса (query string), и какие-то структуры. Вот как раз сижу ковыряюсь.