# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, cucumber

При запуске тестов постоянно получаю одну и ту же ошибку:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')

```
import { Given, When, Then } from '@wdio/cucumber-framework';
import { expect, $ } from '@wdio/globals'
//const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
//const { expect } = require('chai');

Given('I am on the login page', () => {
    // Открываем страницу
    browser.url('https://www.saucedemo.com/');
});

When('I click login button',async () => {
    // Кликаем на кнопку "Login" с айди "login-button"
    const loginButton = $('#login-button');
    loginButton.click();
    await browser.pause(2000);
});

Then('I should see “Epic sadface: Username is required” error message',async () => {
    // Ожидаем, что появится окно с ошибкой и указанным текстом
    const expectedText = "Epic sadface: Username is required"
    const errorMessageElement = $('.error-message-container h3[data-test="error"]')
    await errorMessageElement.waitForExist();
    const errorMessage = await errorMessageElement.getText();
    //console.log(errorMessage+ '-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-==-')
    await expect(expectedText).to.equal(errorMessage);
});
```

Я уже пробовал играться с асинхронностью, проверял константу errorMessage на наличие необходимой мне строки через консоль, пробовал меня метод equal.to() на tohaveTextContaining() ( в этом случае мне напрямую писало что с элемента достается undefined, хотя опять же таки, если выводить его в консоль напрямую - получается строка) Что делать?

Comment: Причина ошибки в том, что [expect(expectedText) возвращает undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Судя по документации, expectedText должно быть элементом HTML, выбранным через селектор вида `$('div')`