# Многомерный массив преобразовать в строчную матрицу

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

В js на вход подается число n.

Необходимо создать двумерный массив n на n, содержащий числа от 1 и по порядку, и вывести в консоль строковую матрицу nxn.

```
Sample Input: n=4
Sample Output:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

```js
let n = parseInt(prompt())
let a = 1
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  arr[i].join('') = []
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    arr[i].push(a)
    a++
  }
}
console.log(arr.join(''))
```

Comment: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - У вас в первой итерации arr[i] не существует

Comment: @SwaD даже если и определен элемент, все равно к нему не получиться применить .join() (либо у меня лыжи не едут)

Answer (score 2):

Предложу еще такой вариант...

Метод `Array.from` создает новый массив из "массивоподобного" объекта `{length: n}`. Поскольку в первом массиве каждый элемент так же массив - для его создания применяется аналогичная конструкция.
Почитать про такое можно тут
https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.761f90d1-65154935-a0ef0ff5-74722d776562/https/www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-an-array-of-given-size-in-javascript/

Метод `forEach` перебирает элементы основного массива. Метод `join` "склеивает" элементы подчиненного массива в строку с указанным разделителем (тут это "пробел").

```js
const n = parseInt(prompt('Укажите количество строк'))
let i = 0
const arr = Array.from({length: n}, _ => Array.from({length: n}, _ => ++i))
arr.forEach(a => console.log(a.join(' ')))
```

Comment: юольшое спасибо

Comment: тзвините за беспокойство, для особо одарённых, не могли бы вы прокоментировать 2 последние строчки или посоветовать где про это почитать поподробнее?

Comment: @MickelGor, дополнил свой ответ...

Answer (score 1):

У вас почти получилось

```js
let n = parseInt(prompt())
let a = 1
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  arr.push([])
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    arr[i].push(a)
    a++;
  }
}
console.log(arr.map(item => item.join(' ')).join('\n'))
```

Comment: спасибо большое!