# Как сделать обработку нажатия кнопки? Ошибка- Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть меню навигации, я его "прячу", следующим образом.

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 0%;
    left: -400px;
}
```

Затем, если у него есть класс `active`, я делаю `left: 0px;`

```
.sidebar.active {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Блок с условной кнопкой в html-файле выглядит так:

```
<div class="sidebar">
        <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="openMenu()">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Навигация</li>
            <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Код функции нажатия, в котором и выдаётся ошибка.

```
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

В теории должно быть так: при нажатии на элемент, у меня должна вызываться функция в js файле, которая позволяет добавить класс `active`, а затем, если он добавился, в css-файле задаётся отступ в 0px. После чего меню становится видно. Полна ошибка выглядит так:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')
    at openMenu (index.html:104:56)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html:14:48)
```

```js
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
}
openMenu();
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  left: -400px;
}

.sidebar.active {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="openMenu()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Навигация</li>
    <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Тест</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) - `getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов, у которой нет свойства **classList**. Или обращайтесь по индексу [0], или используйте querySelector для получения 1го элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка, которую вы видите, связана с тем, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод toggle на объекте, который возвращает getElementsByClassName, и это возвращает HTMLCollection, а не элемент DOM. HTMLCollection не имеет метода toggle.
Для решения этой проблемы вы можете вместо getElementsByClassName использовать querySelector, чтобы получить первый элемент с классом "sidebar".

```
function openMenu() {
    const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
    sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Comment: Если уж вы отвечаете, то лучше это делать с примером кода...