# Ошибка в React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deleteCompletedTask') в компоненте TasksFilter

Tags: reactjs

У меня возникла проблема при разработке приложения на React. У меня есть компонент TasksFilter, который использует контекст для доступа к функции deleteCompletedTask. Когда я пытаюсь вызвать эту функцию в компоненте TasksFilter, возникает ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deleteCompletedTask')".

Я создал контекст в NewTaskForm, где определил эту функцию и передал ее через FilterContext.Provider в TasksFilter. В компоненте TasksFilter я пытаюсь получить доступ к этой функции через context, но получаю ошибку.

```
// NewTaskForm.js
// ...
<FilterContext.Provider
  value={{ deleteCompletedTask: this.deleteCompletedTask.bind(this) }}
>
  {/* ... */}
</FilterContext.Provider>
// ...





// TasksFilter.js
// ...
<button className="clear-completed" onClick={this.context.deleteCompletedTask}>
  Clear completed
</button>
// ...
```

Я не могу понять, почему возникает эта ошибка, и как ее исправить. Буду благодарен за любую помощь в разрешении этой проблемы.

Спасибо!

Comment: [Cannot read properties of undefined](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o). Подозреваю, что this не определено в том месте, где вы хотите это сделать

Comment: в общем пофиксил тем что нужно обязательно экспортить react.createcontext в родителе