# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'positionY')

Tags: javascript

Ошибку возникает из-за следующего кода:

```
const player = players[socket.id];
if(player.positionY <= 0 || player.positionY === 890)
{
    player.positionY += 0;
};
if(player.positionX <= 0 || player.positionX === 1900)
{
    player.positionX += 0;
}
```

координаты заданы в том же файле, в классе. Почему оно их не видит?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что `players[socket.id]` должен существовать?

Comment: player undefined ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'positionY')](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: @SwaD я уж и забыл что такой вопрос есть.... добавил в дубль