# React YMaps3 при анмаунте карты выбрасывает ошибку

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Реализована кастомная карта с кастомно генерируемыми тайлами, так же туда через Clusterer прокидываются маркеры. Но при анмаунте такой карты выбрасывается ошибка `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeFeatureById')`.
При переходи из онлайн карты (стандартные тайлы яндекса) на кастомную (со совими тайлами) все работает штатно, но когда с одной кастомной карты на другую, появляется ошибка.
Появилось именно после добавления Clusterer`а на карту, но отказаться от него нельзя. Не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading \*\*\*)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: Для анализа ошибки нужен минимальный пример кода. Если выложить публично такой пример нет возможности, следует написать в поддержку Яндекс на почту maps-api@support.yandex.ru