# почему мой констант CharacterHtml не работает?

Tags: javascript, api

Написал аниме-сайт в поисках персонажей, но есть ошибка, которую не могу понять уже несколько дней:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var Title = window.document.getElementById("title");
var Img = window.document.getElementById("Image");


const UrlBase = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/characters";

async function getCaracter() {
  var ListCaracters = document.getElementById("ListCaracters")
  const request = await fetch(UrlBase)
  const response = await request.json()
  console.log(response.data)
  const caracters = response.data
  const CaracterHtml = caracters.map((carcater) => {
    `
<div class="CartAnime">
<img id="Image" src="${carcater.images.webp.image_url}" alt="picofAnime">
<h2 id="title">${carcater.name}</h2>
 </div>
`
  })

  ListCaracters.innerHTML = CaracterHtml;
}

getCaracter();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading \*\*\*)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Answer (score 1):

Первая ошибка сообщает о статусе [`429`](https://http.cat/429)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за это в ответе сервера приходит не ожидаемый массив, а что-то.

Для исправления - нужно уменьшить количество запросов к этому api, чтобы оно укладывалось в [указанные ограничения](https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#section/Information/Rate-Limiting)

| Интервал | Количество запросов |
| --- | --- |
| В день | не ограничено |
| В минуту | 60 запросов |
| В секунду | 3 запроса |